# Reparenting the resources of a class to another class

Tags: python, memory

Suppose I have a python object `A` with field `field`. `A.field` is very expensive. Suppose a highly nested dict. At some point, after doing all necessary work with the `A` instance, I call `A.getB()`, which hands me a new kind of object `B`. The function `getB` will chew up and modify `field` in such a way that `field` violates all expectations that `A` had of it, but will be in the necessary form that `B` needs it. If `field` were cheap, I'd simply `deepcopy` it, modify it, and give the copy to `B`, but I can't do that. How do I poison or break `A` so that it isn't reused?

In rust, we have ownership, where the type system could be used to swallow `A` up and prevent it from being used again, but python doesn't provide such guarantees. What would be the most pythonic way to deal with such a situation?

Comment: You can remove the reference to the modified field by doing `del A.field`. Now, trying to access `A.field` will raise an AttributeError.

Comment: Do you need to transform it, or can you write some kind of wrapper function that makes it appear to be transformed? If you're talking about modifying this in-place on `A`, that sounds like a mistake. Create the modified copy if you must, and delete your `A` instance immediately after.

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is that `A` no longer has access to `A.field` you can just use `del A.field`. Note that this will delete the reference `A.field` to your expensive object, not the object itself. The object is only deleted, when there are no references to it. As you handed a reference to it to your object of class `B`, this is not the case.

Alternatively, you could just set `A.field = None`. This would prevent an AttributeError when trying to access `A.field`.

Or is your goal to get rid of the whole object of class `A`? Then again, you could delete or overwrite any variable referencing this object. Your expensive object referenced via `A.field` would not be impacted by that, as it is still referenced through your `B` object:

```py
a = A()
# do expensive stuff
b = a.getB()
del a
```